# Least Squares Linear Programming with inequalities

Tags: numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, euclidean-distance

I am using Numpy `np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=-1)` to solve a system of equations with an approximate solution via the Least Squares method.

However I realised the approximate solution contains negative values for the coefficients of some dimensions. So I would like to add boundaries to make all the dimensions only positive. I think this means adding inequalities to the system of equations. It seems SciPy has this with `from scipy.optimize import linprog` - however this is requiring myself to specify a function to minimise which in my case is the "Least Squares" norm, but I don't know how to define that. AFAIU There is no default function. How do I use SciPy `linprog` with some sort of default least square norm as the minimisation function?

This is the code with NumPy:

```py
import numpy as np

# This is a matrix representing fertilisers, 
# i.e. products with various chemical elements in them
A = np.array([[1.04e+01, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00,
        3.00e+00, 1.20e+01, 9.00e+00],
       [7.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 5.00e+01, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00,
        3.00e+01, 6.00e+00, 5.00e+00],
       [2.70e+01, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 9.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00,
        3.00e+01, 2.90e+01, 3.90e+01],
       [0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 1.50e+01, 2.00e+00, 1.60e+01, 0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 2.00e+00],
       [7.00e+00, 1.50e+01, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 7.00e+00, 0.00e+00],
       [0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 3.00e+01, 0.00e+00, 3.00e+01, 0.00e+00,
        0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 1.12e+01],
       [0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 5.00e-01, 1.00e-02, 0.00e+00, 6.00e-01,
        1.00e-01, 1.00e-02, 1.00e-02],
       [0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 2.00e-02, 0.00e+00, 5.00e-01,
        0.00e+00, 1.60e-01, 4.00e-02],
       [0.00e+00, 5.00e-01, 5.00e-01, 2.00e-03, 1.00e+00, 1.50e+00,
        1.00e-01, 4.00e-02, 2.00e-03],
       [0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 2.00e-03, 5.00e-01, 2.00e-01,
        0.00e+00, 1.00e-02, 2.00e-03],
       [0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 1.00e-03, 0.00e+00, 2.00e-01,
        1.60e+00, 6.00e-03, 2.00e-03],
       [0.00e+00, 5.00e-01, 5.00e-01, 1.00e-02, 1.50e+00, 2.10e+00,
        1.00e-01, 8.00e-02, 1.00e-02],
       [4.10e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 8.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 0.00e+00,
        3.00e+00, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00]])

# this is a vector representing a given "recipe" 
# for desired quantities of each chemical element
b = np.array([[8.0e+01],
       [4.5e+01],
       [1.0e+02],
       [5.0e+01],
       [2.0e+02],
       [1.8e+02],
       [5.0e-01],
       [3.0e+00],
       [5.0e-01],
       [5.0e-02],
       [5.0e-02],
       [5.0e-01],
       [0.0e+00]])

# the optimisation solution
x_solution = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=-1)
x_approx_sol = x_solution[0]
x_residuals = x_solution[1]

# the "new b" according to the optimised "x solution"
b_approx = A.dot(x_approx_sol)
```

As you can see `x_approx_sol` contains negative numbers, which means negative quantities for each fertiliser, but I would like to have only 0 or positive quantitites:

```
array([[ -7.06529347],
       [ 12.62140023],
       [ 16.79436939],
       [  6.67404177],
       [-13.95259075],
       [  2.26982817],
       [-11.05480032],
       [  8.58752025],
       [  8.08066117]])
```

So I think I should add an array of "boundaries" with 9 elements as `(0, float("inf"))` to the SciPy `linprog`. How do I define the distance norm to minimise? It should be the Euclidean 2-norm || b - a x ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looking for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html which is an implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares.

In this case replace `lstsq` with `nnls` (`b` also needs to have only one dimension):

```
# the optimisation solution
x_approx_sol, x_residuals = nnls(A, b.squeeze())

# the "new b" according to the optimised "x solution"
b_approx = A.dot(x_approx_sol)

assert (x_approx_sol >= 0).all()

print(x_approx_sol.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Gives

```
[[ 0.        ]
 [11.50294958]
 [ 5.44866408]
 [ 0.36370257]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 3.84407344]
 [ 0.        ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am not looking for a non-negative B vector (above here `b_approx`, although that's implicit speaking of quantities in chemistry). I am looking for a non-negative X vector (above here this is `x_approx_sol`, the list of quantities of fertilisers), but I checked that output and indeed it's non-negative :)

Comment: @TPPZ I've updated the answer to reflect your _actual_ question 

Answer (score 1):

**Linear** Programming won't help you with your **non-linear objective**. In regards to general-purpose constrained-optimization, you would want to target convex quadratic-programming or second-order cone programming. But no need to use those *very general tools* (more general = less robust).

Either go for:

- David's approach which is a very good candidate for small/medium-sized *dense problems*

  - probably the easiest approach
- or use [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy-optimize-least-squares)

  - a bit more work due to it's support for *non-linear functions*
  - sparse algorithms available
- or build your own minimizer based on [L-BFGS-B](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html)

  - even more work
  - has been much more efficient compared to NNLS for me when instances became large!

> So I would like to add boundaries to make all the dimensions only positive. I think this means adding inequalities to the system of equations.

Keep in mind, that you want to introduce *variable-bounds* which *could* be introduced by linear-equalities, but usually these kind of constraints are enforced explicitly (e.g. modification of simplex-method; *projection* onto bounds etc.). The 2n and 3rd approach both support variable-bounds, but not general (or even linear) constraints: somewhat indicates, that those are not equally hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`Scipy.optimize` provides `nnls`, non-negative least squares. For general box constraints, use `least_squares` for non-linear optimization or `lsq_linear` for linear problems with box constraints.